# meaning of a sentence from kill bill 2

Tags: meaning-in-context

I can't figure out the meaning and structure of this sentence:

> Budd: If you're gonna compare a Hanzo sword, you compare it to every other sword ever made... that wasn't made by Hattori Hanzo.

Before this sentence, someone asks the character to compare a Hanzo sword which she is holding in her hands to another Hanzo sword.

Comment: *Structurally*, the "sentence" is a complete mess. The speaker knows Hanzo swords are ***all*** "incomparably good", and it's clear he intends to emphatically reject the possibility of classifying any particular one as better or worse than any other. But he doesn't know how to empress this coherently after saying *ever made*. So he ends up pausing and throwing in *wasn't made .... by Hanzo*, leaving it to the girl to recognise she just committed a *faux pas* by implying that *any* Hanzo sword could ever be found inferior to anything (which it can't be if one avoids comparison to another Hanzo)

Comment: If you saw the film, you wouldn't expect that kind of character to produce anything better than that.

Comment: @user96526  Could you edit the titla so it has proper capitals? It's not much to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "If you're gonna compare a Hanzo sword.. ...you compare it to every other sword ever made - wasn't made - by Hattori Hanzo."

It means:

> If you're gonna compare a Hanzo sword [to anything], you compare it to every other sword which was ever made [but which] wasn't made by Hattori Hanzo.

I other words, you shouldn't compare a Hanzo sword with another Hanzo sword. You should compare it with all the non-Hanzo swords that have ever been made.